# Macbook pro 15 inch 2017 freezes until hard reboot

Tags: macbook-pro, mojave, performance

My 15 inch MacBook pro running Mojave (10.14.6) recently started freezing randomly staying completely unresponsive. I use an external monitor and all I see is the screensaver frozen, when disconnected the MacBook's screen remains black.

I tried resetting the SMC, PRAM, and VRAM but it happened again. The problem goes away momentarily when I hard reset the computer. I checked and there's no crash reports to be found after the reboot. I checked the SSD with DiskUtility and no problem was found.

I have a copy of system.log and I know the approximate time of today's freeze, but I don't know how to read the log file, I can copy the log file if necessary.

What else can I do to diagnostic my computer?? Or does anyone know what could be happening?

Thanks.

Comment: Check this [page at Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/diagnose-problems-mh35727/10.14/mac/10.14) about how to diagnose problems with your Mac using built-in diagnostics.

Comment: I followed the instructions on that site but I only get a warning about the battery. Thing is I always use it plugged in so I doubt the battery is freezing the computer

Comment: What's the warning? Even if you always leave it plugged in, battery problems can cause a host of problems.

Comment: That it doesn't hold as much charge that it initially did, but it's still operating normally

Comment: That's a 'normal' warning. Batteries age and become less efficient over time, just like people. Are there any other correlations you can find that can point to some specific event or circumstance that precede the freeze? I.e. Running a specific app or combination of apps; time of day. Although it may hinder your productivity, can you try using the MBP without the external monitor for a day? If this is not possible, try a known good interconnection cable. Also, wiggle the interconnect cable a little at both the MBP and the monitor ends (no need to be too forceful) to see if that causes a hang.

Comment: Well, some weird behavior started when I changed my USB-c hub -- it connects and disconnects my external HDD for no reason. I've wiggled the monitor cable but it doesn't cause a hang. I'll try reverting back to my old hub and see how it goes. Other than that my workspace has been fairly standard, with the same amount of opened apps (and the same apps) which usually are chrome, atom, email, whatsapp, telegram, slack. What I did have was a tonne of tabs in chrome, but I closed them all and the pc still hanged

Comment: Ahh! The unmentioned USB hub!

Comment: Seems like such a minor thing... It even has its own power source... Well I'm without it now so I'll check if that's the problem or not

Comment: in our company 5 of us are experiencing the same issue since yesterday. Looks like a global issue, but hard to say if it's Apple software or third party software related. Also see https://twitter.com/FlorianSanson/status/1308070631620182017 (i don't know the guy but same issue in his company)

Comment: I've changed my external usb-c hub and as of now my macbook hasn't frozen yet, so fingers crossed that was it for me. Do you have any external things plugged in?

Comment: i'm not connected to any device. I noticed in the syslog that at the time of each crash i had a line related to our supervision software: RG Supervision. I just uninstalled it to check if it's the cause of the issue or not.